# how to create crowdsale with openzipplin 4.x without crowdsale contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

i'm new to blockchain development and i was following a tutorial for making an ICO, but he uses openzipplin 2.x and crowdsale contracts that are already implemented on it, i saw on the doc that those contracts are not in the versions 3.x and 4.x, so i'm wondering what is the best way to create icos now, if its from scratch? or maybe i can run two versions of openzipplin in same project? or how can i create my token using OZ 4.x and then import it in an other project that uses OZ 2.x !
thanks for your futur help